# What are X11 errors and why do I keep getting them?

Tags: c#, events, mono, x11, porting

I'm working on a project in which I'm rewriting an old visual basic project into c#, then porting it to mono on linux terminal with a touch screen. In order to port I place the .exe files into my linux directory and run them from terminal with the mono runtime command, ie: "mono program.exe" I have working code in my c# and have come a long way, but here is my current issue:

The app I'm porting is similar to a terminal you would use at an airport to print your boarding passes, just for the inter-modal transportation industry. It is a **database driven** application as well, so I dynamically load controls onto the page. In light of all this, on the home screen I have some labels, **a textbox, an image, and a virtual keyboard.** The textbox is where the user enters values and they can click either the image or the virtual keyboard enter key in order to submit their data to the database. As the page processing functions get called from these click events, I show a new panel (not in the designer) over top of the controls on the form in order to stop other events from getting through (part of the old vb design as well).

Here is my event raising from the image:

```
    private void ctlPictureBox_MouseUp(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        _IsDown = false;
        ctlPictureBox.Invalidate();
        if (KioskLinux.Modules.Common.__TypeMode == 0) {
            if (ButtonEval(e.X, e.Y)) {
            //Event Handling is better than Sendkeys!
            //System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys.Send("{" + _ImageMethod + "}");
                EventHandler handler = KeyControlSelection;
                if (handler != null)
                {
                    handler(this, e);
                    Console.WriteLine("handler(this, e)");
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Here is my event handling for the image, this is an event that I made:

```
    void OnKeyControlSelection(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            ProcessPage(sender, ((KioskLinux.ProgramaticControls.KioskUI_KeyControl)sender)._ImageMethod); //Whatever key I am, do the ImageMethod
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error 1 in KioskLinux.Forms.frmMain.OnKeyControlSelection : " + ex);
        }

    }
```

Here is my event raising from the keyboard: I should mention that I find which key has been pressed, by mapping out a jpeg image and sending the corresponding key from a hash table.

```
    private void ctlkeyboard_MouseUp(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (ButtonEvalMap(e.X, e.Y, ref row, ref col) && KioskLinux.Modules.Common.__TypeMode == 0)
        {
            _LastRow = -1;
            _LastCol = -1;

            _DurationHeld = (System.DateTime.Now.Ticks - _TickDown) / 10000;
            SendKey(sender, e, row, col);
            this.ctlKeyboard.Invalidate();
        }
        else if (KioskLinux.Modules.Common.__TypeMode == 1)
        {
            if (ButtonEvalMap(e.X, e.Y, ref row, ref col) & KioskLinux.Modules.Common.__TypeMode == 1)
            {
                _LastRow = -1;
                _LastCol = -1;

                _DurationHeld = (System.DateTime.Now.Ticks - _TickDown) / 10000;
                SendKey(sender, e, row, col);
                this.ctlKeyboard.Invalidate();
            }
        }
    }

    public void SendKey(object sender, EventArgs e, int Row, int Col)
    {
        string KeyCode = string.Empty;
        //Due to a SendKeys incompatibility in mono with the "{ESC}" key, we had to simulate an "{ESC}" Keypress using its own eventhandler rather than sendkeys like everything else
        try
        {
            KeyCode = _KeyTable[Row.ToString() + "," + Col.ToString()].ToString();
            if (KeyCode == "{ESC}") {
                EventHandler handler = EscapeButtonPressedOnKeyboard;
                if (handler != null)
                {
                    handler(this, e);
                }
            }
            else {
                System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys.Send(KeyCode);
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error 1 in KioskLinux.ProgramaticControls.KioskUI_Keyboard.SendKey : " + ex);
        }
    }
```

Here is my event handling for the keyboard (Sendkeys generates keypress events, and my main form has keypreview before the textbox gets the keys):

```
    public void frmTablet_KeyPress(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        EnsureFocus();
        if (e.KeyChar == (char)13)
        {
            bool FoundHost = false;
            foreach (Control KeyPress_Culprit in this.pnlBrowserCase.Controls)
            {
                if ((KeyPress_Culprit is KioskLinux.ProgramaticControls.KioskUI_TextBox) || (KeyPress_Culprit is KioskLinux.ProgramaticControls.KioskUI_CombTextBox)) //If one of these on pnlBrowserCase
                {
                    FoundHost = true;
                    e.Handled = true;
                    //Logic stuff for Robust Scenario Handling
                    ProcessPage((KioskLinux.ProgramaticControls.KioskUI_TextBox)KeyPress_Culprit, "ENTER"); //They are both DirectCasted as KioskUI_Textbox in VB code
                }
            }
            if (!FoundHost)
            {
                foreach (Control KeyPress_Culprit in this.pnlBrowserCase.Controls)
                {
                    if (KeyPress_Culprit is KioskLinux.ProgramaticControls.KioskUI_KeyControl) //Enter KeyPress must have been generated by this
                    {
                        e.Handled = true;
                        ProcessPage((KioskLinux.ProgramaticControls.KioskUI_KeyControl)KeyPress_Culprit, "ENTER");
                    }
                }
            }

        }
        //Sendkeys does not work with ESC key in mono, and has a fatal error (core dumped)
        //I needed to use a "translation" to make sure the Virtual Keyboard ESC key would work on Linux using the # key, which is otherwise unused
        //The first case statement allows a "go back" from a "go back control"
        else if (e.KeyChar == (char)91 || e.KeyChar == (char)27) // Check for # or ESC character
        {
            if (MapKeyboardLastScreenToKeypressESC() == false)
            {
                foreach (Control KeyPress_Culprit in this.pnlBrowserCase.Controls)
                {
                    if (KeyPress_Culprit is KioskLinux.ProgramaticControls.KioskUI_KeyControl)
                    { //ESC KeyPress must have been generated by this
                        if (KeyPress_Culprit.Text == "ESC") {
                            e.Handled = true;
                            ProcessPage((KioskLinux.ProgramaticControls.KioskUI_KeyControl)KeyPress_Culprit, "ESC");

                        }

                    }
                }
            }
            //This allows a keyboard/virtual keyboard press to do what an escape KeyControl on the page would do.
            else
            {
                foreach (Control KeyPress_Culprit in this.pnlBrowserCase.Controls)
                {
                    if (KeyPress_Culprit is KioskLinux.ProgramaticControls.KioskUI_KeyControl)
                    { //ESC KeyPress must have been generated by this
                        if (KeyPress_Culprit.Text == "ESC")
                        {
                            e.Handled = true;
                            ProcessPage((KioskLinux.ProgramaticControls.KioskUI_KeyControl)KeyPress_Culprit, "ESC");

                        }

                    }
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            e.Handled = false;
        }
    }

    void OnEscapeButtonPressedOnKeyboard(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Due to a SendKeys incompatibility in mono with the "{ESC}" key, we had to simulate an "{ESC}" Keypress using its own eventhandler rather than sendkeys like everything else
        KeyPressEventArgs myKeyPressEventArgs = new KeyPressEventArgs((char)(27));
        frmTablet_KeyPress(this, myKeyPressEventArgs);
    }
```

When I use the virtual keyboard to process the page, it works beautifully in mono, however when I use the image I get an x11 error in mono. I think it has to do with the fact that my event is not being handled with the image click when it processes page in the main form class, but I'm unsure:

Here is my stacktrace in mono:

```
X11 Error encountered: 
  Error: BadWindow (invalid Window parameter)
  Request:     40 (0)
  Resource ID: 0x1C000B5
  Serial:      4077
  Hwnd:        Hwnd, Mapped:True ClientWindow:0x1C000B5, WholeWindow:0x1C000B4, Zombie=True, Parent:[Hwnd, Mapped:True ClientWindow:0x1C000B1, WholeWindow:0x1C000B0, Zombie=True, Parent:[<null>]]
  Control:     <handle 1C000B5 non-existant>   at System.Environment.get_StackTrace()
   at System.Windows.Forms.XplatUIX11.HandleError(IntPtr display, XErrorEvent ByRef error_event)
   at System.Windows.Forms.XplatUIX11.XTranslateCoordinates(IntPtr , IntPtr , IntPtr , Int32 , Int32 , Int32 ByRef , Int32 ByRef , IntPtr ByRef )
   at System.Windows.Forms.XplatUIX11.ScreenToClient(IntPtr handle, Int32 ByRef x, Int32 ByRef y)
   at System.Windows.Forms.XplatUIX11.GetMessage(System.Object queue_id, MSG ByRef msg, IntPtr handle, Int32 wFilterMin, Int32 wFilterMax)
   at System.Windows.Forms.XplatUIX11.PeekMessage(System.Object queue_id, MSG ByRef msg, IntPtr hWnd, Int32 wFilterMin, Int32 wFilterMax, UInt32 flags)
   at System.Windows.Forms.XplatUIX11.DoEvents()
   at System.Windows.Forms.XplatUI.DoEvents()
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.DoEvents()
   at KioskLinux.Forms.frmMain.Reload()
   at KioskLinux.Forms.frmMain.ProcessPage(System.Object sender, System.String Method)
   at KioskLinux.Forms.frmMain.OnKeyControlSelection(System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
   at KioskLinux.ProgramaticControls.KioskUI_KeyControl.ctlPictureBox_MouseUp(System.Object sender, System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnMouseUp(System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmLButtonUp(Message ByRef m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message ByRef m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control+ControlWindowTarget.OnMessage(Message ByRef m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control+ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message ByRef m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.WndProc(IntPtr hWnd, Msg msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
   at System.Windows.Forms.XplatUIX11.DispatchMessage(MSG ByRef msg)
   at System.Windows.Forms.XplatUI.DispatchMessage(MSG ByRef msg)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.RunLoop(Boolean Modal, System.Windows.Forms.ApplicationContext context)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.ShowDialog(IWin32Window owner)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.ShowDialog()
   at KioskLinux.Modules.modUtilities.Main()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to invoke, because you have to sync the threads..

```
    public delegate void delInvokeForm(Form form, string arg1, string arg2);

    internal void InvokeForm(Form form, string arg1, string arg2)
    { 
        if (form != null)
        {
            if (form.InvokeRequired)
            {
                form.BeginInvoke(new delInvokeForm(InvokeForm), form, arg1, arg2); //you can add more args..
            }
            else
            {          
        //...do        your stuff here
    }
        }
    }
```